# Each retorna sempre o último termo de uma tabela JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código que percorre uma tabela que contém dados, mas não sei o porque que ele retorna sempre o último item quando eu seto um objeto. Ele não retorna os outros itens.

Código:

```
$('.btn-finalizar-pedido').click(function () {

  //sessionStorage.removeItem('dadosproduto');

  let objeto_1 = [];
  let obj_1 = new Object();

  var produtosArray1 = "";
  var id_produto_selecionado = "";
  var nome_produto_selecionado = "";
  var comprimento_produto_selecionado = "";
  var largura_produto_selecionado = "";
  var espessura_produto_selecionado = "";
  var quantidade_produto_selecionado = "";
  var preco_produto_selecionado = "";
  var novo_preco_produto_selecionado = "";

  $('.tabela-produtos .produtos-tabela tr').each(function()
  {
    id_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_id_selecionado').text();
    nome_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_nome_selecionado').text();
    comprimento_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_comprimento_selecionado').text();
    largura_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_largura_selecionado').text();
    espessura_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_espessura_selecionado').text();
    quantidade_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_quantidade_selecionado').text();
    preco_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_preco_selecionado').text();
    novo_preco_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_novo_preco_selecionado').text();

    obj_1.id_produto = id_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.quantidade = quantidade_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.comprimento = comprimento_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.largura = largura_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.espessura = espessura_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.novo_preco = novo_preco_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.preco_produto = preco_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.nome = nome_produto_selecionado;

    objeto_1.push(obj_1);

    produtosArray1 = JSON.stringify(objeto_1);
    console.log(produtosArray1);
    sessionStorage.setItem('dados', produtosArray1);
  });
});
```

Tentei assim:

```
  let objeto_1 = [];
  let obj_1 = new Object();

   $('.btn-finalizar-pedido').click(function () {

   var produtosArray1 = "";
   var id_produto_selecionado = "";
   var nome_produto_selecionado = "";
   var comprimento_produto_selecionado = "";
   var largura_produto_selecionado = "";
   var espessura_produto_selecionado = "";
   var quantidade_produto_selecionado = "";
   var preco_produto_selecionado = "";
   var novo_preco_produto_selecionado = "";

   $('.tabela-produtos .produtos-tabela tr').each(function()
   {
id_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_id_selecionado').text();
nome_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_nome_selecionado').text();
comprimento_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_comprimento_selecionado').text();
largura_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_largura_selecionado').text();
espessura_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_espessura_selecionado').text();
quantidade_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_quantidade_selecionado').text();
preco_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_preco_selecionado').text();
novo_preco_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_novo_preco_selecionado').text();

obj_1.id_produto = id_produto_selecionado;
obj_1.quantidade = quantidade_produto_selecionado;
obj_1.comprimento = comprimento_produto_selecionado;
obj_1.largura = largura_produto_selecionado;
obj_1.espessura = espessura_produto_selecionado;
obj_1.novo_preco = novo_preco_produto_selecionado;
obj_1.preco_produto = preco_produto_selecionado;
obj_1.nome = nome_produto_selecionado;

objeto_1.push(obj_1);

  produtosArray1 = JSON.stringify(objeto_1);
  sessionStorage.setItem('dadosproduto', produtosArray1);
  });

 });
```

Também não deu muito certo. O que será que está de errado no código?

Comment: O que é .tabela-produtos e .produtos-tabela?

Comment: São classes de quais elementos?

Comment: Pelo código ele sempre retorna o último item porque você está criando um novo array (`objeto_1`) toda vez que o elemento com a classe `.btn-finalizar-pedido` é clicado.

Comment: Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259792/91352

Comment: .tabela-produtos .produtos-tabela tr = .tabela_produtos = tabela table e produtos-tabela é um tbody

Comment: @AndreGusmao já tentei mas não deu certo

Comment: @ÐvÐ  
.tabela-produtos .produtos-tabela tr = .tabela_produtos = tabela table e produtos-tabela é um tbody

Comment: Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcar ✔

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é colocar o `let obj_1 = new Object();` dentro do laço para que a cada *loop* o objeto seja recriado, caso contrário o JavaScript entende que o objeto é o mesmo e sobrescreve a array com o último valor passado.

O código ficaria assim:

```
$('.btn-finalizar-pedido').click(function () {

  //sessionStorage.removeItem('dadosproduto');

  let objeto_1 = [];

  var produtosArray1 = "";
  var id_produto_selecionado = "";
  var nome_produto_selecionado = "";
  var comprimento_produto_selecionado = "";
  var largura_produto_selecionado = "";
  var espessura_produto_selecionado = "";
  var quantidade_produto_selecionado = "";
  var preco_produto_selecionado = "";
  var novo_preco_produto_selecionado = "";

  $('.tabela-produtos .produtos-tabela tr').each(function()
  {

    let obj_1 = new Object();

    id_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_id_selecionado').text();
    nome_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_nome_selecionado').text();
    comprimento_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_comprimento_selecionado').text();
    largura_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_largura_selecionado').text();
    espessura_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_espessura_selecionado').text();
    quantidade_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_quantidade_selecionado').text();
    preco_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_preco_selecionado').text();
    novo_preco_produto_selecionado = $(this).find('.prod_novo_preco_selecionado').text();

    obj_1.id_produto = id_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.quantidade = quantidade_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.comprimento = comprimento_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.largura = largura_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.espessura = espessura_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.novo_preco = novo_preco_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.preco_produto = preco_produto_selecionado;
    obj_1.nome = nome_produto_selecionado;

    objeto_1.push(obj_1);

    produtosArray1 = JSON.stringify(objeto_1);
    console.log(produtosArray1);
    sessionStorage.setItem('dados', produtosArray1);
  });
});
```